# js error when submit any form in voyager laravel

Tags: javascript, php, laravel, voyager

i have just create new laravel project and then include the Voyager package [as document](https://voyager.readme.io/v0.11/docs/installation)

and i have done [configuration](https://voyager.readme.io/v0.11/docs/configurations) of the project

after serve the project and access to admin control panel ,
i can't submit any form
for example : when i press save on editing permission on role gave me javascript erorr :

```
SCRIPT438: Object doesn't support property or method 'set'
```

[image: that after pressing submit]

and this happen to me in every voyager admin control panel forms

your kind help is very appreciated

Comment: What version of Internet Explorer are you using?

Comment: i am use :
Microsoft Edge 41.16299.248.0
Microsoft EdgeHTML 16.16299